# AWS CDK: AWS-ec2 SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' after update node

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I update NX and related versions. so now using node `14.15.0` instead of node `12.20.2`

node version updated. so I update the `aws-cdk` packages. but now the following command is not working anymore. the issue is the optional chaining operator in `aws-ec2`.

`npx env-cmd -f pipeline.json npx ts-node --project ./scripts/tsconfig.json ./apps/cloud-infrastructure/src/bin/pre-build.ts`

I get the following error when I fire the above command.

[image]

node version `14.15.0`. (tried in another version as well)

[image]

**compiler options in ts config** `tsconfig.base.json`

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true
}
"files": [
    "./polyfills.localize.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "tmp"
  ]
```

ts config

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["node", "jest"],
    "lib": ["ES6", "ES2017", "es2015", "ES2020.Promise"],
    "module": "CommonJS"
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Comment: What's your TS version?

Comment: 4.2.4 @Richard Dunn

Comment: What have you set as the `target` in `../tsconfig.base.json`?

Comment: I using es2015 as a target

Comment: Ok, well then that tsconfig has nothing to do with the code that's generating the error because target: es2015 would have transpiled away the conditional chaining operator. I guess there's more to your configuration than you've shown?

Comment: I updated. I using nx

Comment: As I mentioned, that tsconfig isn't being used when compiling that JS. Also, that version of node doesn't appear to be the one you're using either as 14.15 should support the optional chaining operator. I don't use NX so can't help you much there, but I think it's probably not working the way you think it is.

Comment: I found "node" separately in the package.json  and it's 12.x. so update it to 14.x and working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on [this](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/4144#issuecomment-1303536527) answer to a GitHub issue, you probably need to update Node from 12 (either to 14 or 16). The best way to do this is to update your package file, run `npm update`, then resolve dependency issues.